# VS Code not showing complete type information when hover

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am new to TypeScript and not sure if it is a bug and I set something wrong. So I have this line of code in my React functional component:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState<{email: string}|null>(null);
```

When I hover over `user`, I see `const user: {email: string;}` while I am expecting `const user: {email: string;}|null`. And when I use`user.email` in the following lines, I don't see any warning like "Object is possibly 'null'.".

[image: missing type information]

Is this the expected behavior? If so, what is the right way to type a nullable state variable?

I am using TypeScript Version 3.9.7 and here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".next", "out"],
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "**/*.js"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabling the "strict" compiler option enables all strict type checking options including "strictNullChecks". Not having it enabled will not give you the "Object is possibly 'null'." warning.

You can explicitly enable this by adding the option to your tsconfig.json.

```
"strictNullChecks": true
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!